# Exactly parse string to datetime format

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string as follows:

```
'Mon, 7 Apr 2014 13:46:23 +0300'
```

I'd like to parse this COMPLETE string to datetime format?

Could any of your guys help me about this? I could not see on manual.

Thank you!

Comment: _I could not see on manual._ You sure ? [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: Did you try to parse it? I don't see any problems with this string.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran Sorry, bit tired. Saw it! Thanks! I got it fixed.

Comment: @curiozity, Glad you got it, You can delete your question , else people will keep downvoting your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what would help you:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Mon, 7 Apr 2014 13:46:23 +0300'));
```

for setting to date format refer to [PHP's Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the manual (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Additionally you have work on the +300. The note in the manual sasys:
Note:
The timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored when the time parameter either contains a UNIX timestamp (e.g. 946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

So it might also be parsed.